# Postgres connection leaks - idle in transaction (aborted)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have a Rails multi-threading app that is causing Postgres connection leaks. Eventually when I try to make a new connection, it tells me I have too many clients.

When I look at the current connections, I see a bunch of connections that have this status: "idle in transaction (aborted)". What does this mean, and most importantly is there a way to have Postgres periodically check for these types of connections, and to terminate them if they remain for a prolonged period of time?

I know the best way to fix this is to fix the app issue, but other than that, how can I ensure these types of stale connections don't clog up the connection pool?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So a semi-hackish way is to get rid of processes that have the idle in state (aborted) status for more than 5 mins. You can put this in a Cron Job:

```
SELECT pg_terminate_backend(pid)
FROM pg_stat_activity 
WHERE datname = 'DBNAME'
  AND pid <> pg_backend_pid()
  AND state = 'idle in transaction (aborted)' 
  AND state_change < current_timestamp - INTERVAL '5' MINUTE
```

For postgres version ≤ 9.1, you might want to try this :

```
SELECT pg_terminate_backend(pid)
FROM pg_stat_activity
WHERE datname = 'DBNAME'
  AND procpid <> pg_backend_pid() 
  AND current_query = '<IDLE> in transaction (aborted)'
  AND query_start < current_timestamp - INTERVAL '5' MINUTE
```

Answer (score 5):

For the "what does it mean" part of the question, my answer is that your application probably does not correctly handle SQL errors : the postgres connection raises an error that the application fails to detect and does not rollback the transaction. So the connection remains *"in transaction (aborted)"* forever.